# Mascara de porcentagem com o react-input-mask no react js com typescript

Tags: react, typescript, mask

**tenho que criar uma mascara para um input no projeto já estamos utilizando o react-input-mask https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask#beforemaskedstatechange**

**A solução não necessariamente precisa utilizar  o React-Input-mask.**

Ele adianta muita coisa.

Mas para criar uma mascara dinamica com o simbolo de % que precisa ficar ao lado do numero to levando uma pisa.

**aqui tem tem o link de um code sandbox que achei de um cara que criar uma mascara para cpf e cnpj
https://codesandbox.io/s/brava-react-masked-input-8xe2p?file=/src/App.js**

tbm estou utilizando o formik

**Embaixo como deve ser o campo e a mascara comportamento da máscara.**

O campo deve estar em branco para que eu possa inserir A
PORCENTAGEM;

O campo deve aceitar apenas NÚMERO DE acima de 1 até 100, incluindo 100;

O campo aceita somente valores inteiros;

O campo não deve aceitar LETRAS ou caracter especial;

A usuária deve visualizar o simbolo % no campo ao lado do número digitado;

O usuário deve visualizar em tela a PORCENTAGEM inserida;

```
<Input
        width="auto"
         value={formik.values.beneficiaries[index]["percentage"]}
         name={`beneficiaries.${index}.percentage`}
         id={"percentage" + index}
         optional={false}
         label="Porcentagem"
         mask={"999%"}
         maskPlaceholder={""}
         error={!!(errors.beneficiaries[index] && errors.beneficiaries[index}["percentage"])}
         errorDescription={errors.beneficiaries[index] ? errors.beneficiaries[index]["percentage"]: ""}
         change={formik.handlerChange}
         blur={formik.handleBlur}
         focus={handleOnFocus}
    />
```

o mask comentado é uma propriedade do react-Input-Mask onde fica o "9" ele especifica que vai receber numero e o % só aparece após digitar os três números, não quero utilizar o jqueryMask, pois já estamos utilizando o React-Input-mask no projeto por ele sé mais "simple".

**Pode ser uma solução sem o React-Input-mask**. espero ter descrito meu problema bem no aguardo :D

Comment: já tentou assim: `<MaskedInput name="porcento"  mask="999%" value=values.porcento} onChange={handleChange}  />`

Comment: ao fazer isso o input deixa de receber entrada de valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pessoal consegui a solução, sem utilizar uma lib apenas utilizando o **toLocaleString**
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring_number.asp

criei uma função

```
//regexs para converter e mascara.

 const convertMaskPercent = (value: string) => {
  return (parseInt(value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")) * 0.01).toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "percent" });
  
};

const removeCharactersAndSpecialCharacter = (value: string) => {
  return value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
};

// mascara campo porcentagem      
const handlerChangeMaskPercent = (event: any) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    if (Number.isNaN(parseInt(removeCharactersAndSpecialCharacter(value)))) {
      formik.setFieldValue(name, "");
    } else {
      var newValue = convertMaskPercent(value);
      formik.setFieldValue(name, newValue);
    }
  };

 // limitar valor até 100 é limpar valores maiores
  const onBlurMaskPercent = (event: any) => {
    let {name, value} = event.target
    let parseValue = parseInt(value)
      if(parseValue > 100 || parseValue < 0){
        formik.setFieldValue(name, "");
      }

  };
```

COMO FICOU O INPUT!

````
<Input
                                width="auto"
                                value={
                                  formik.values.beneficiaries[index][
                                    "percentage"
                                  ]
                                }
                                name={`beneficiaries.${index}.percentage`}
                                id={"percentage" + index}
                                optional={false}
                                label="Porcentagem"
                                maskPlaceholder={""}
                                error={
                                  !!(
                                    errors.beneficiaries[index] &&
                                    errors.beneficiaries[index]["percentage"]
                                  )
                                }
                                errorDescription={
                                  errors.beneficiaries[index]
                                    ? errors.beneficiaries[index]["percentage"]
                                    : ""
                                }
                                change={handlerChangeMaskPercent}
                                blur={onBlurMaskPercent}
                                focus={handleOnFocus}
                                maxCharacters={4}
                              />

```
````